# Autoincrementing number unique id in Solr

Tags: java, search, solr, solrj

I want to generate unique keys automatically in solr. I checked the default function [here](http://solr.pl/en/2013/07/08/automatically-generate-document-identifiers-solr-4-x/)
but it is generating id like 1cdee8b4-c42d-4101-8301-4dc350a4d522. In my application, I need unique autoincrement numbers like we do in MySql. What should be approach to do this ? Solrj pointers would be much helpful.

Comment: '1cdee8b4-c42d-4101-8301-4dc350a4d522' is a universally unique identifier (UUID).  You can use the UUID() function in MySQL to generate one.

Comment: no, but it is about further processing those numbers. I have to make use of numbers and I am not using MySQL. Is selecting highest id and then increment from there in solrj while inserting a good option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution (hack) that I've implemented is to create a record in solr inside the existing schema. For example if you have a schema which has 2 string fields then you can store the values as MAX_VALUE and the other being the actual integer max value stored as string. So anytime you would add, you'd have to query for "fieldname:MAX_VALUE" and retrieve the string value from the other field of the same document. You can parse it and add 1. You then update the existing MAX_VALUE document. It's not the most feasible but it is a solution. The implementation keeps your max number within your index rather than in another application.

It's also solj friendly as it's fairly straight forward to make the query and the update query.

I apologize for the grammar. Do comment if you can't understand what I'm saying.

Comment: I got the idea. Added a new field    <field name="maxvalue" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/> . but solr is giving error when I try to add a value to start with, unique key is not available. Need to figure out some work around.

Comment: The field type doesn't have to be long. If you're using solrj with java then store it as a string then parse it as long when you retrieve it.

Comment: This will not work in concurrent scenario. Consider scenario when two users  simultaneously do this. They both will do described procedure and two documents will get the same number and will have `fieldname == MAX_VALUE`. The problem is that the check-modify-save is not atomic in this solution.

Comment: Update to my comment above: starting from solr 4 you CAN increment a value in a document and detect if any conflict with concurrent update happen. This allows to implement the solution described in this answer if proper handling of atomicity is done: execute atomic increment and repeat if conflict happen.